# Execute command as administrator to restore mysql database in win7 via CMD

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd

I'm trying to restore a mysql backup in XAMPP - Windows 7 using the following command:

```
mysqlimport.exe -u username -p password nameOfNewDB < backupFile.sql
```

The machine I'm working on is attached to a network, so I checked my username using whoami and I got:

```
rms\johndoe
```

So I tried:

```
mysqlimport.exe -u rms\johndoe -p password nameOfNewDB < backupFile.sql
```

it asks me for the password, after entering it, it says:

**Error: 1045 Access denied for user 'rms/johndow'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

Then I tried only with johndoe, same error, then I tried using .\admin (I've got the admin password), same error, I also tried .\administrator, admin, administrator and nothing yet.

**Note:** I'm using cmd because the database is very large and I cannot do it using phpmyadmin.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: username and password should be username and password of DB not local windows users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using root as username an the password of your root user.